# how to remove duplicated id's from $result1

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to php....plzz help for this below mentioned condition.
I have  tables.

table 1-Literature

```
author_lit| literature_id|  title1      |      title2
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
thomas    |      1      |   xxxxxxx |  yyyyyyyy
------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------
Mr.xxx     |      2     |    xxxx            |  Yyyyy
-------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
```

table 2-Organism

```
Org_id |    literature_id|  name    |   type
-------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
1      |    1            |  xxxx    | yyyyy
-------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
2      |     2           |xxxx      |Yyyyy
-------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
```

table 3- Biogeography

```
Bio_id  |literature_id| title1     | title2         |  Org_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |   1         | xxxxxx     | Marian species |   1
------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |   1         |  xxxx      | Yyyyy          |   2
------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

table 4- common_name

```
Com_id  |literature_id| title1  |title2 |Org_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |      2      | xxx     |yyyy   |1
------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |       2     | xxxx    |Yyyyy  |2
------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUwVG.png)

---

As per above tables lit table have details of literature and org table,bio,com table has reference of literature in the form of literature_id. now i want to fetch those  literature_id from all tables go to literature table fetch details of literature and display.

Example:-
organism id '1' has references literature _id 1,1,2 from table Organism,Biogeography,common_name.
Now i wanted to display all references and their details of literature for org_id '1'($org1).

how to do it?? and how to remove recurring  literature _id?? since it will only repetition while displaying record.(details will be same of  literature for  literature_id).

I used below code for doing the same but my output that can be seen in result  image. Its wrong because record is getting repeated; I want no duplication when I display records. please help me....

the code is:

```
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT lit.literature_id,  lit.title1, lit.title2
                        FROM lit
    INNER JOIN Organism  on lit.literature_id = Organism.literature_id
                        WHERE organism_id='$org1'
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT lit.literature_id,  lit.title1, lit.title2 
                        FROM lit
                        INNER JOIN biogeography  on lit.literature_id = biogeography.literature_id
                        WHERE organism_id='$org1'
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT lit.literature_id,  lit.title1, lit.title2
                        FROM lit
                        INNER JOIN ecology  on lit.literature_id = ecology.literature_id
                        WHERE organism_id='$org1'

                        ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {
                        echo "
                        <td>$row[0]</td>
                        <td><i><b>'$row[1]',
                        '$row[2]'</i></b><br>

                        </td>
                        <td>$row[8]</td>

                                </tr>";
```

Comment: @naruto-Please check the result image. I want to remove the repeated records.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT lit.literature_id,  lit.title1, lit.title2
                        FROM lit
    INNER JOIN Organism  on lit.literature_id = Organism.literature_id
                        WHERE organism_id='$org1'
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT lit.literature_id,  lit.title1, lit.title2 
                        FROM lit
                        INNER JOIN biogeography  on lit.literature_id = biogeography.literature_id
                        WHERE organism_id='$org1'
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT lit.literature_id,  lit.title1, lit.title2
                        FROM lit
                        INNER JOIN ecology  on lit.literature_id = ecology.literature_id
                        WHERE organism_id='$org1' group by lit.literature_id 

                        ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {
                        echo "
                        <td>$row[0]</td>
                        <td><i><b>'$row[1]',
                        '$row[2]'</i></b><br>

                        </td>
                        <td>$row[8]</td>

                                </tr>";
```

Comment: ,hi i tried this code bt i doesnot remove repeated records from table.please see the result image.there record is repeating i wanted eliminate that.

Comment: since $result1 contains duplicate  id's if i remove those  duplicated id's and

Comment: pass the unique id's to fetch data than my problem will be solved. But how to do it?.i tryed "array_unique($result1)" but it doesn't work. plzz help..

Comment: please check result image that i have already posted,that's the output

Comment: but still the output is-Array ( [0] => 8 ) Array ( [0] => 10 ) Array ( [0] => 10 )

Comment: the array still contains id 10 repeated

Comment: if you give full result of mysql than i change a query and your output @prati

Comment: @kelvin-Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => Domestic Sponge [2] => Historical and industrial use of sponges )
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => Sponge1 [2] => dfsgth )
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => Sponge1 [2] => dfsgth )

Comment: you use my query ?
because I have already group by use for 'lit.literature_id'

Comment: i used group by still its same..plz post code that will remove duplicates from resultant $result1